# PHP POST request not returning correct value

Tags: php

I'm creating a Gmail bot for my work which will check Gmail accounts and see if they require phone verification or not, but I'm stuck on a problem - for some reason, it's giving me an error when I try to make the call and return the html page.

```
<?php
$url="http://accounts.google.com/AccountLoginInfo";
$data = array('Email' => 'gmail_username', 'Passwd-hidden' => 'gmail_pass');


$options = array(
    'http' => array(
        'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'content' => http_build_query($data)
    )
);
$context  = stream_context_create($options);
$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
//print($result);
if ($result === FALSE) { 
    print("error");
}
?>
```

Comment: Seeing what that error is would be good

Comment: What isn't working exactly? Do you have any errors? What have you tried to fix it? Please read and follow the instructions on this page to produce a high-quality question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask